# PHP Form (post) Repeating input in a tabel

Tags: php

I have a form (with post method) that takes the following input:
- a certain name
- a number
- 3 checkboxes

All this input gets generated and calculated in a table.(html code within the php)
Everything gets properly calculated and displayed in a table.

**So my question:**
How do i make it possible after giving all those input to give in more input?
Meaning i have made a hyperlink that goes back to the form itself (where i can give the input).
So i can give in new data, and after submiting that again the table now contains 2 rows of values insteed of just 1.

Not really sure what exactly i need for this. (i use 2 php files, one for the form, then another one where the table gets displayed (and where all my calculations are placed).

Regards.

Comment: The simplest way would be to merge your two php files into one. If the form was submitted you make the insert, display a message like "Row added." and then reprint the form.  
Or didn't I understand you correctly?

Answer (score 1):

> How do i make it possible after giving
>   all those input to give in more input?
>   Meaning i have made a hyperlink that
>   goes back to the form itself (where i
>   can give the input). So i can give in
>   new data, and after submiting that
>   again the table now contains 2 rows of
>   values insteed of just 1.

You could place new text input after form has been submitted like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
?>
  <!-- Your initial/previous form -->
  <form>
    <!-- Your initial/previous form iputs -->

    <!-- now your news input text -->
    <input type="text" name="whatever" />
  </form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, then i hope You need to place an UPDATE query instead of INSERT